# MS Graph API on behalf of user - unsuccess

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api

On this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#IntegratedWindowsProvider it is said "*The interactive flow is used by mobile applications (Xamarin and UWP) and desktops applications to call Microsoft Graph in the name of a user.*"

So I developed a C# console app to login and query some data:

```
var clientId = "<APP GUID GOES HERE>";  
var tenantId = "<APP TENANT GUID GOES HERE>";  

var scopes = new[] {"user.read","Calendars.Read"};
var clientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder  
    .Create(clientId) 
    .Build();  


var authProvider = new InteractiveAuthenticationProvider(clientApplication, scopes);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

User me =  graphClient.Me.Request()
    .GetAsync()
    .Result;
```

During running the console app a login "page" comes out, I entered my credentials, but at the end the pagse says error "*AADSTS500113: No reply address is registered for the application.*", and the code got "*user cancelled the login*"

BTW: I dont want to login manually each time, I added my password to the code:

```
var scopes = new[] {"offline_access","user.read","Calendars.Read"};
var clientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder  
    .Create(clientId) 
    .Build();  
var authProvider = new UsernamePasswordProvider(clientApplication, scopes);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
var pwd = ConvertToSecureString("<MYPASSWORD GOES HERE>");

User me =  graphClient.Me.Request()
    .WithUsernamePassword("<MY EMAIL GOES HERE>", pwd)
    .GetAsync()
    .Result;
```

In this case no login page shows up (good), but an exception raises: "*The grant type is not supported over the /common or /consumers endpoints. Please use the /organizations or tenant-specific endpoint.*"

Then I added a `WithTenantId(...)` to the `Build()`, now I got different exception: "*MsalUiRequiredException: AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000*'." but the multi-factor auth request does not come to my phone.

What goes wrong? What should I do to get this app work?

What I want is to execute this c# console app regularly on my desktop computer, without any interactions (logins) as my user to query some data using graph api. How to do that correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This error `AADSTS500113: No reply address is registered for the application` indicates that the reply URL is not available and AAD does not know where to send the token. To fix this, you need to add a valid redirect URI in your app registration in AAD.

The next error : [MsalUiRequiredException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.msaluirequiredexception?view=azure-dotnet) in your case happens because the user needs to perform multiple factor authentication based your Azure AD policies. To do this, you need to change your flow from the current username/password provider to [interactive authentication provider](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-auth#c-interactive-authentication-provider) since in the former case, users who need to do MFA won't be able to sign-in (as there is no interaction).

This would look something like this:

```
IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .Build();
InteractiveAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new InteractiveAuthenticationProvider(publicClientApplication, scopes);
```

You can then acquire the token interactively :

```
string[] scopes = new string[] {"user.read"};
var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId).Build();
var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
AuthenticationResult result;
try
{
 result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
             .ExecuteAsync();
}
catch(MsalUiRequiredException)
{
 result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
             .ExecuteAsync();
}
```

To authenticate without the user, your app can implement [client credentials](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-credential-flows) acquisition methods - these suppose that the app has previously registered a secret (application password or certificate) with Azure AD, which it then shares with this call. Please note that no user interactions means you can't use delegated permissions.

Let me know if this helps and if you have further questions.

Comment: I understand what you said - but: still dont know what is a 'valid redirect URI' for a console application running on local host. Then I understand that me as a user must log in using two factor auth, but this is an app with much more less permissions than me. And I wanted to run this app in background scheduled. So you says me as the user must take action every time the app tries to log in and query my outlook events? Hm.

Comment: Another question - how to construct a "console" app which logins with token or somehow, and queries some data from a given user who allowed this kind of query for the given app.